# Can't seem to allow incoming connections on a specific port, Mac OS X 10.6.1

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, firewall, port

I want to be able to allow incoming connections on a specific port regardless of the program currently running.

This is mainly so I can temporarily let users from other machines access ruby on rails apps in development.

The Snow Leopard firewall UI doesn't seem to allow this, only can specify it on an application by application basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using [**WaterRoof**](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/index.html) to manage the firewall. It's a GUI frontend for dealing with ipfw (the FreeBSD sponsored open source firewall you have). For action, leave it as **allow** and for protocol use **any**. Set the IP addresses and port you want opened accordingly.

[image]